# Rancher running an APP that needs internet access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

**Rancher v 1.6.10, Docker v 17.06.2-ce**

I'm deploying a stack via Rancher UI that contains one of the docker containers that has an app which connects to Dropbox via the internet. But the app isn't able to access the internet.

However, if I don't use rancher and simply use docker-compose up natively, then it all works fine.

The networking that the Rancher creates appears to be the problem I guess.

Can I be advised please?

My docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
      container_name: es1
      environment:
        - cluster.name=idc-cluster
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        - xpack.security.enabled=false
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
      mem_limit: 1g
      volumes:
        - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ports:
        - 9200:9200
      networks:
        - docker-elk
  idcdb:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=DriveMe
      - POSTGRES_USER=idc
      - POSTGRES_DB=idc
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/db
  idcredis:
    image: redis:4.0
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/var/lib/redis
  booking-service:
      environment:
       - PORT=8085
       - PROFILE=integration
      ports:
       - 8085:8085
      image: idc/idc-booking-service
      depends_on:
        - idcdb
        - idcredis
  notification-service:
        environment:
         - PORT=8087
         - PROFILE=integration
        ports:
         - 8087:8087
        image: idc/idc-notification-service
        depends_on:
          - idcredis
  analytics-service:
        environment:
         - PORT=8088
         - PROFILE=integration
        ports:
         - 8088:8088
        image: idc/idc-analytics-service
        depends_on:
          - idcredis
          - elasticsearch1
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.6.3
    environment:
          - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch1:9200"
    networks:
          - docker-elk
volumes:
  pgdata: {}
  redisdata: {}
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
    docker-elk:
      driver: bridge
```

Comment: show your docker file

Comment: I have copied the docker compose file above. Does this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the networks while starting docker

```
--net=host
```

if this does not solve your problem

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
comment out the following line:

#dns=dnsmasq
```

then

sudo restart network-manager

Comment: --net=host didn't work because my docker-compose.yml has references to database "idcdb" and this resolution is broken when I added net=host. I don't see this file: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. I'm using rancheros.iso image on my VM.

Comment: I'm on a Mac/OSX but my Docker host (rancher agent node) is a `Linux rancher-agent-1 4.9.45-rancher #1 SMP Sun Aug 27 23:25:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: the microservice (on container A) is not able to resolve the database by name (on container B). It was working without --net=host

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Rancher LB](http://blog.programster.org/rancher-deploying-a-load-balancer) and add it to your application as follows:

1. In the stack where you application is you will have to click on *Add Service* button and select *Add a Load Balancer*
2. Then you make sure that where is says *Access* is set to Public
3. In the Request Host you will have to add the desired URL such as: mylocal.dev
4. Then you will have to add the port 80 so it will be accessible from the outside world on port 80
5. Select the service you want the LB to apply for and the internal application port.

Thats' all :) now you should be able to connect to mylocal.dev from the outside world.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to achieve otherway around. The app inside my container needs access to the internet (access dropbox).